# Scala Pattern match on a list with at `@` symbol an extractor

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to access a reference of the first element

```
List(Some(1), None) match {
  case x@Some(1) :: xs => x
  case _ => None
}
res0: java.io.Serializable = List(Some(1), None)
```

The pattern matches correctly.

However I expected `x` to be the `Some(1)`, that is the head of the list, and *NOT* the list itself.

How can I both use the extractors *AND* have a reference to the element?

Answer (score 1):

I made it work just wrapping the element in parentheses

```
val lst = List(Option(1), None)
lst match {
  case (x@Some(1)) :: xs => x
  case _ => None
}
res0: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

And it works also for multiple extractors!

```
val lst = List(Option(1),Option(2), None)
lst match {
  case (x@Some(1)) :: (y@Some(2)) :: xs => y 
  case _ => None
}
```

Comment: `x @ SimplePattern`. So the alternative syntax for `case x: X` is `case x @ (_: X)` where parens are required because type pattern `_: X` is not a "simple" pattern. The other footnote is no bindings in alternatives: `case x @ p | y @ q`.